# Graficar múltiples columnas vs tiempo python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Existe algún scripts en python que permita graficar cada columna vs Tiempo todo a la vez. Graficando la columna "Fecha" en X vs "Aeropuerto"-"Barranquillita"-"elCasco" en tipo de grafica lineal  y scatter. He graficado pero individual Fecha-Aeropuerto. Gracias

```
 import pandas as pd
 dfP2 = pd.read_csv('ConsolidadoPreci2.csv', parse_dates=['Fecha'])
 dfP2

dfP2.info()
     #   Column                            Non-Null Count  Dtype         
    ---  ------                            --------------  -----         
     0   Fecha                             8248 non-null   datetime64[ns]
     1   AEROPUERTO LOS CEDROS [12015070]  8212 non-null   float64       
     2   BARRANQUILLITA [12010030]         8236 non-null   float64       
     3   CASCO EL [12010070]               8225 non-null   float64                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.figure()

    plt.plot(dfP2["Fecha"], dfP2["UNIBAN [12015020]"], 'b')
    plt.show(1)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fecha,AEROPUERTO LOS CEDROS [12015070],BARRANQUILLITA [12010030],CASCO EL [12010070],CHIGORODO [12015110],EUPOL [12010100],LORENA LA [12010060],NUEVO ORIENTE [12010170],PALMERA LA [12015090],PISTA INDIRA - AUT (12015100),PRADO MAR [12010110],SANTA MARTHA [12010120],TORMENTO EL [12010010],TOSCANA LA [12010050],TRIGANA [12010090],TULENAPA  - AUT [12015060],UNIBAN [12015020],VILLARTEAGA [12015010]
1999-01-01,2.0,0.0,0.0,,0.0,36.0,,,,0.0,0.0,0.0,29.0,0.0,0.5,,
1999-01-02,0.0,6.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,,,0.0,0.0,0.0,16.0,37.0,1.9,,
1999-01-03,25.6,12.0,29.0,,9.0,0.0,,23.0,,0.0,8.0,0.0,43.0,1.0,4.4,,
1999-01-04,0.0,10.0,0.0,,0.0,94.0,,5.0,,0.0,0.0,71.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,,
1999-01-05,24.0,1.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,0.3,,0.0,14.0,5.0,19.0,0.0,4.6,,
1999-01-06,0.0,0.0,1.4,,0.0,20.0,,0.0,,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,,
1999-01-07,0.0,0.0,16.7,,0.0,0.0,,19.0,,0.0,0.0,18.0,1.0,0.0,0.4,,
1999-01-08,8.4,15.0,8.0,,0.0,74.0,,29.0,,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,7.3,11.5,
1999-01-09,54.8,29.0,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,4.8,,0.0,55.0,20.0,43.0,130.0,147.3,114.0,

Comment: Buen día, por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye algunas líneas de tu dataframe así como la información sobre qué columnas deseas graficar y el tipo de grafica (Barras, scatter, etc) que deseas utilizar

Comment: Acabo de ver que agregaste algunas líneas del dataframe pero por favor agrégalas como texto para que podamos copiar y pegar para ayudarte más rápidamente

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato

Comment: Ahora lo reviso, existe alguna restricción en cuanto a módulos a utilizar para graficar? O sería posible utilizar algún módulo similar o basado en matplotlib?

Comment: no se @HeytalePazguato, considero que no hay ningún problema en referencia a los módulos. Lo que busco es que se grafiquen todas las estaciones en un solo scripts (individual). Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Una forma muy fácil de hacerlo es utilizar el módulo [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) y la gráfica [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot)

Utilizando la información que pusiste en tu pregunta cree un archivo (sample.csv) que genera el siguiente `dataframe` (Como tiene varias columnas lo segmenté para poder visuzliarlo en la respuesta)

```
            AEROPUERTO LOS CEDROS [12015070]  BARRANQUILLITA [12010030]  \
Fecha                                                                     
1999-01-01                               2.0                        0.0   
1999-01-02                               0.0                        6.0   
1999-01-03                              25.6                       12.0   
1999-01-04                               0.0                       10.0   
1999-01-05                              24.0                        1.0   
1999-01-06                               0.0                        0.0   
1999-01-07                               0.0                        0.0   
1999-01-08                               8.4                       15.0   
1999-01-09                              54.8                       29.0   

            CASCO EL [12010070]  CHIGORODO [12015110]  EUPOL [12010100]  \
Fecha                                                                     
1999-01-01                  0.0                   NaN               0.0   
1999-01-02                  0.0                   NaN               0.0   
1999-01-03                 29.0                   NaN               9.0   
1999-01-04                  0.0                   NaN               0.0   
1999-01-05                  0.0                   NaN               0.0   
1999-01-06                  1.4                   NaN               0.0   
1999-01-07                 16.7                   NaN               0.0   
1999-01-08                  8.0                   NaN               0.0   
1999-01-09                  0.0                   NaN               0.0   

            LORENA LA [12010060]  NUEVO ORIENTE [12010170]  \
Fecha                                                        
1999-01-01                  36.0                       NaN   
1999-01-02                   0.0                       NaN   
1999-01-03                   0.0                       NaN   
1999-01-04                  94.0                       NaN   
1999-01-05                   0.0                       NaN   
1999-01-06                  20.0                       NaN   
1999-01-07                   0.0                       NaN   
1999-01-08                  74.0                       NaN   
1999-01-09                   0.0                       NaN   

            PALMERA LA [12015090]  PISTA INDIRA - AUT (12015100)  \
Fecha                                                              
1999-01-01                    NaN                            NaN   
1999-01-02                    NaN                            NaN   
1999-01-03                   23.0                            NaN   
1999-01-04                    5.0                            NaN   
1999-01-05                    0.3                            NaN   
1999-01-06                    0.0                            NaN   
1999-01-07                   19.0                            NaN   
1999-01-08                   29.0                            NaN   
1999-01-09                    4.8                            NaN   

            PRADO MAR [12010110]  SANTA MARTHA [12010120]  \
Fecha                                                       
1999-01-01                   0.0                      0.0   
1999-01-02                   0.0                      0.0   
1999-01-03                   0.0                      8.0   
1999-01-04                   0.0                      0.0   
1999-01-05                   0.0                     14.0   
1999-01-06                   0.0                      0.0   
1999-01-07                   0.0                      0.0   
1999-01-08                   0.0                      0.0   
1999-01-09                   0.0                     55.0   

            TORMENTO EL [12010010]  TOSCANA LA [12010050]  TRIGANA [12010090]  \
Fecha                                                                           
1999-01-01                     0.0                   29.0                 0.0   
1999-01-02                     0.0                   16.0                37.0   
1999-01-03                     0.0                   43.0                 1.0   
1999-01-04                    71.0                    0.0                 0.0   
1999-01-05                     5.0                   19.0                 0.0   
1999-01-06                     0.0                    0.0                 0.0   
1999-01-07                    18.0                    1.0                 0.0   
1999-01-08                     0.0                    0.0                 0.0   
1999-01-09                    20.0                   43.0               130.0   

            TULENAPA - AUT [12015060]  UNIBAN [12015020]  \
Fecha                                                      
1999-01-01                        0.5                NaN   
1999-01-02                        1.9                NaN   
1999-01-03                        4.4                NaN   
1999-01-04                        0.0                NaN   
1999-01-05                        4.6                NaN   
1999-01-06                        0.0                NaN   
1999-01-07                        0.4                NaN   
1999-01-08                        7.3               11.5   
1999-01-09                      147.3              114.0   

            VILLARTEAGA [12015010]  
Fecha                               
1999-01-01                     NaN  
1999-01-02                     NaN  
1999-01-03                     NaN  
1999-01-04                     NaN  
1999-01-05                     NaN  
1999-01-06                     NaN  
1999-01-07                     NaN  
1999-01-08                     NaN  
1999-01-09                     NaN
```

Lo importante es mencionar que la columna "Fecha" ha sido utilizada como índice

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col = 'Fecha')
```

Y lo único que hay que hacer es indicarle a la gráfica `lineplot` el `dataframe` que vamos a utilizar

```
sns.lineplot(data=df)
```

Como son varias columnas hay que cambiar el tamaño de la gráfica para que se pueda vizualizar mejor

```
sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(15,8)})
```

Ejemplo completo (Nota, estoy dejando matplotlib en el ejemplo por si en un futuro quieres cambiar la posición de la leyenda o alguna otra propiedad de la gráfica):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col = 'Fecha')
sns.set(rc = {'figure.figsize':(15,8)})
sns.lineplot(data=df)
```

Esto produce la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: que teso @HeytalePazguato. Muchas gracias por ayudarme con el problema.